# Derived class causes InsertOnSubmit() to throw NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, nullreferenceexception

I did look at the related posts that were answered, but still get the `NullReference` exception in `InsertOnSubmit()`.
I have an auto generated `LINQ` class Transaction from which I create a derived class that overrides `ToString()`:

```
public partial class MyTransaction:DataAccess.Transaction
{
    public MyTransaction():base()
    {

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {

        return "some text";
    }

}
```

And the insert is as follows:

```
public bool InsertTransaction(Transaction t)
    {
        using (MarketPricesDataContext dataContext = new MarketPricesDataContext(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {                
                dataContext.Transaction.InsertOnSubmit(t);
                dataContext.SubmitChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

I thought calling the base constructor from `MyTransaction` would solve my problem, but it did not. I can insert Transaction items but when I try to insert a `MyTransaction` item I get a `NullReferenceException`.
This works:

```
Transaction t=new Transaction();
t.Type="A"; //set some values
Data d=new Data();
d.InsertTransaction(t);
```

This throws a `NullReferenceException` (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) in `InsertOnSubmit()`:

```
MyTransaction myt=new MyTransaction();
myt.Type="A"; //set some values
Data d=new Data();
d.InsertTransaction(myt as Transaction);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that may not be supported, but I would at least expect a better exception  :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ-to-SQL already supports inheritance, but only for types in the model. I imagine it is looking for your *custom* type in the model (to find the appropriate table or discriminator), and failing.

In short, I don't think you can use subtypes that **aren't** part of the model.

However, the types are `partial`; you should be able to do:

```
namespace MyTransaction:DataAccess {
    partial class Transaction {
        public override string ToString() {
            return "some text";
        }
    }  
}
```

which adds your `ToString()` override into the *generated* type.

Comment: Yes, you have the right idea and it helped me to find the solution. I added another answer to show what I did to solve the problem in my context. Unable to give you a +1 as my reputation is less than 15.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Marc for pointing me in the right direction. To solve the problem, I did away with the `MyTransaction` class and in the `DataAccess` namespace, the one containing the `DataContext` and Linq-to-SQL classes, I override `ToString()` as follows:

```
namespace DataMining.DataAccess
{
public partial class Transaction
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
      return "some text";
    }

}
}
```

I now use `Transaction` where I before would have used `MyTransaction`.